# Django - Class based views is returning a blank page

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use the class based views to create a page where I can delete an article by his ID.

here is the codes to create the pages where I can delete my articles.

**views.py**

```
class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(id=request.POST['article_id'])
        article.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="views.article.DeleteView" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ article.views.id }}"</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', DeleteView.as_view(), name="DeleteView"),
```

Here is my problem > the page is not rendering, I'm getting a blank page without anything on it, how can I fix this?

******* EDIT *******

**views.py**

```
class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(id=request.POST['article_id'])
        article.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = Article.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        context = {"article": article}
        return render_to_response("template.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit in template file:

```
<form action="{% url "DeleteView" %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="acticle_id" value="{{ article.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Pleas, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url). The template file should end with `html`, not `py`.